# Can't install Angular2 2.0 final

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to upgrade to the latest version of Angular2, but all I can seem to find references to is Beta17

I've run npm view angular2 and the last few lines of that are pretty much:

```
 '2.0.0-beta.13',
 '2.0.0-beta.14',
 '2.0.0-beta.15',
 '2.0.0-beta.16',
 '2.0.0-beta.17'
```

I get a similar result from Visual Studios intellisence.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: On npm the latest version is 2.0.0-beta.17, there are a bunch of RCs and a 2.0.2 version on GitHub tough: https://github.com/angular/angular/releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After beta17, angular moved into scoped packages. So you will have to use **@angular** instead of angular2 like this-

```
npm view @angular/core
```

List of angular2 packages-

```
"@angular/common": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/core": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/http": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/router": "~3.0.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.2",
```

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart